# How add a views page url to the admin_menu?

Tags: users

I tried creating a view with a page display, giving it a normal menu item in navigation, the url admin/people/allusers (or any url like admin/content/listing), clearing the caches, but the admin menu does not pick up the page and put it in the drop downs.

How do I do this without having to use hook_menu for each views page url I want in the admin menu bar?

Answer (score 3):

The link needs to get added to the Management menu to show up in admin_menu.

You can add a admin menu link on:
http://example.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/management

Or through the interface at : Structure->Menus->Management->Add Links

Comment: OH! thanks. putting it in management totally worked (I had looked for Administration, a d6 thing, but didn't know what management was for). I thought I was going crazy. :)

Comment: Glad it works - not crazy! Thanks for all your help recently!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @ursula, you can add view with a page display link from Structure->Menus->Management->Add link (admin/structure/menu/manage/management) in admin menu.

Please see the image where I have added Archive View link under Reports menu. I have specified following 3 fields in the 'Add link' form,

Menu link title - Archive View
Path - Archive
Parent link - ----Report

[image]